# Arduino doesn't act on serial data when sending a lot of data itself

Tags: arduino

I'm trying read sensor data from my Arduino and send commands via USB to make it run it's motors and servos. When I don't send any sensor data to the PC it seems to work fine, but when I start sending data it stops acting on the commands and usually the motors won't stop running until I restart the Arduino.

This is my code:

```
unsigned long serialdata;
int inbyte;
int packetIndex;
int packet[5];

float magOutput[4];
float mpuOutput[7];
long outputMillis = 0;

char openChar = '{';
char closeChar = '}';
char seperatorChar = '/';

bool isRecieving = false;
bool packetWaiting = false;

void recieveSerial() {
  if (packetWaiting) {
    return;
  }

  inbyte = Serial.read();
  if (!isRecieving) {
    if (inbyte == openChar) {
      isRecieving = true;
      packetIndex = 0;
      serialdata = 0;
    }
    return;
  }

  if (inbyte == seperatorChar) {
    packet[packetIndex] = serialdata;
    packetIndex++;
    serialdata = 0;
    return;
  }

  if (inbyte == closeChar) {
    packetWaiting = true;
    isRecieving = false;
    return;
  }

  if (inbyte > 0) {
    serialdata = serialdata * 10 + inbyte - '0';
  }
}

void sendSerial() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - outputMillis > 20) {
    outputMillis = currentMillis;

    Serial.print(openChar + '0' + seperatorChar);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      Serial.print(magOutput[i]);
      Serial.print(seperatorChar);
    }
    Serial.print(magOutput[3]);
    Serial.println(seperatorChar);

    Serial.print('1' + seperatorChar);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      Serial.print(mpuOutput[i]);
      Serial.print(seperatorChar);
    }
    Serial.print(mpuOutput[6]);
    Serial.println(seperatorChar + closeChar);
    Serial.flush();
  }
}
```

The PC sends commands like this, '{0/0/1/255}' as in {motors/motor 1/forwards/speed 255}, once when I press the up arrow for example.

Is there a way to make sure the Arduino receives and acts upon my commands while sending data to the PC?